# How to check a cell forward 1 for a turtle?

Tags: netlogo

Im looking to modify this code so that the turtle will only move into the cell that is forward 1 if there isn't already a turtle in there.

```
ask turtles
  [ let close-friend min-n-of 1 turtles with [my-group = [my-group] of myself] [distance myself]
  ask close-friend

  [ face myself
  forward 1
  ]
]
```

I looked at adding adding the number of turtles from forward 1 to a variable and then a IF statement  but i couldn't get it to work.

Any reply's will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if there's any turtle's on the patch ahead:

```
if not any? other turtles-on patch-ahead 1 [forward 1]
```

You may want to check if the turtle can move forward first because patch-ahead may report nobody.

```
if can-move? 1 and not any? other turtles-on patch-ahead 1 [forward 1]
```

Comment: Whether or not it is clearer is arguable, but you can use `if can-move 1` instead of `if patch-ahead 1 != nobody`. See the doc for [`can-move?`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#can-move).

Comment: `other` is necessary here because `patch-ahead 1` might actually be the same patch the turtle is already standing on, if the turtle's heading isn't a multiple of 90. If that seems surprising, see Next Patch Example in the Code Examples section of NetLogo's Models Library.